# Dp with memoize

Tags: dynamic-programming

This is a problem in 'introduction to algorithm' dp chapter

We have to cut a long steel in order to gain most benefits

[image]

the first line is length and the second line is price.

```
def cut_rod_mem(n, p):
m = [0]
for i in range(10):
    m.append(-1)

def inner(n, p):
    if m[n]!=-1:
        return m[n]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        t = p[i] + inner(n - i, p)
        if t > m[n]:
            m[n] = t
    return m[n]

return inner(n,p)
```

I am confused if this list will be out of range?

Comment: If this is Python then it should be tagged as such and the indentation should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be out of range because the elements of array are indexed from `0 to n-1`, i.e in the above case `0 to 9`. In the function inner the for loop goes from `1 to n`, thus inner`(n - i, p)` is in range with values `inner(9, p)` ..... `inner(0, p)`.